# Contents file missing in http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had trouble finding ros packages since I use apt-file and I had not noticed that it did not use the ros repository. That is because the Content file is missing.

So can this be fixed? Where should I create an issue?

Or is there any other way to find in which ros deb a file is in?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57499/contents-file-missing-in--http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described on the [Ubuntu install page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1), released ROS packages are built to debs with the ROS distribution (ros-groovy-) and stack name for dry packages, or package name for wet packages.

For example, if you were interested in installing [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://ros.org/wiki/teleop_twist_keyboard) for Groovy, you could visit the wiki, observe that it is a dry package inside of the brown_remotelab stack, and install the ros-groovy-brown-remotelab package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-09**:
Yes, for certain scenarios that works. But apt-file is a standard way to find stuff the should work. Why use a non-standard method when there exist a standard method?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-10**:
We're using reprepro to generate the repository, and it doesn't generate the Contents file by default. Fixed.